# Форма не проходит валидацию

Tags: form, symfony2, symfony3

Столкнулся с проблемой, что форма не проходит валидицию, причём независимо от того, правильно значение передано или нет. Также такое происходит только на одном поле *skuBrand*.

Я так же убрал все *Validation Assert* в сущности. Не понимаю, почему метод *$form->isValid() = false*.
Анализировал *request*. В нём есть значение (*Id* объекта) и этот объект есть в базе данных. Переменная *{{ form_errors(form) }}* ошибок не показывает.

Как можно понять по каким причинам не проходит форма валидация?

Код:
Класс формы

```
class FiltersType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $securityContext;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('barcodeConsumer', array(  'required' => false,  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.barcodeConsumer',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('barcodeConsumer', 'text', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('barcodeLogistics', array(  'required' => false,  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.barcodeLogistics',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('barcodeLogistics', 'text', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('name', array(  'required' => false,  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.name',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('name', 'text', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('nameShort', array(  'required' => false,  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.nameShort',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('nameShort', 'text', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('skuCategory', array(  'multiple' => false,  'em' => 'default',  'class' => 'Nitra\\SchemaCDBBundle\\Entity\\SkuCategory',  'required' => false,  'group_by' => 'skuGroup.name',  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.skuCategory',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('skuCategory', 'entity', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('skuBrand', array(  'multiple' => false,  'em' => 'default',  'class' => 'Nitra\\SchemaCDBBundle\\Entity\\SkuBrand',  'required' => false,  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.skuBrand',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('skuBrand', 'entity', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('skuType', array(  'multiple' => false,  'em' => 'default',  'class' => 'Nitra\\SchemaCDBBundle\\Entity\\SkuType',  'required' => false,  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.skuType',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('skuType', 'entity', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('externalKey1', array(  'required' => false,  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.externalKey1',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('externalKey1', 'text', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('externalKey2', array(  'required' => false,  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.externalKey2',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('externalKey2', 'text', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('status', array(  'required' => false,  'choices' =>   array(    0 => 'Нет',    1 => 'Да',  ),  'empty_value' => '',  'label' => 'fields.skuGlobal.status',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('status', 'choice', $formOptions);


    }

    protected function getFormOption($name, array $formOptions)
    {
        return $formOptions;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'filters_skuglobal';
    }

    public function setSecurityContext($securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

}
```

Сущность SkuGlobal

```
    class SkuGlobal extends BaseEntity {

    use \Nitra\SchemaCDBBundle\Model\TranslatableEx;

    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->translate()->getName();
    }
     /**
     * Бренд СКЮ
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SkuBrand", inversedBy="skuGlobals")
     */
    protected $skuBrand;
}
```

Сущность SKU_Brand.

```
class SkuBrand extends BaseEntity
{

    use \Nitra\SchemaCDBBundle\Model\TranslatableEx;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->translate()->getName();
    }

     /**
     * Глобальные СКЮ привязанные к бренду
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SkuGlobal", mappedBy="skuBrand")
     */
    protected $skuGlobals;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->skuGlobals = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->target = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->promotionSkuListDetail = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->updateTranslations();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы отобразить ошибки по которым  форма не прошла валидацию нужно сделать следующие вещи. 1 Создать объект типа Validator и вызвать метод validate с передачей в него объекта проверки.

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($form);
```